# JS defineProperty set undefined

Tags: javascript, mocking

I have tests and I want to redefine `Promise` like my own function. But when I try to do it I get `Promise` like `undefined`. I can't realize how fix that.
My test block:

```js
const data = 'server template';
const PromiseCorrect = Promise;
const PromiseMock = { lol: 12 };
Object.defineProperty(window, 'Promise', PromiseMock);

const file = await getFile({ template: { guid: 'guid' } }, undefined, false, () => true, () => true);
expect(file).toBe(data);

Object.defineProperties(window, 'Promise', { value: 'bar', configurable: true });
```

Console output:

```
console.log src/pages/WebTemplate/components/SpreadSheet/lib/utils.js:67
      ----> undefined
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty, pay attention to the third argument.

Comment: @georg how can I rewrite `Promise` if it has writeble false ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized a problem.

```js
    const data = 'server template';
    const PromiseCorrect = Promise;
    const PromiseMock = { value: jest.fn() };
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'Promise', PromiseMock);

    const file = await getFile({ template: { guid: 'guid' } }, undefined, false, () => true, () => true);
    expect(file).toBe(data);

    Object.defineProperties(window, 'Promise', { value: 'bar', configurable: true });
```

That works correct.